# Fitting two Gaussians on less expressed bimodal data

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, scikit-learn, curve-fitting

I am trying to fit two Gaussians on a bimodal distribution [data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1gl3t7uhym64029/data.csv?dl=0), but most of the optimisers give me wrong results always based on starting guess as below
[image]

I also tried `GMM` from `scikit-learn`, which didn't help much. I am wondering what I may be doing wrong and what is better approach so that we can test and fit the bimodal data. One of the example code using `curve_fit` and [data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1gl3t7uhym64029/data.csv?dl=0) is as follows

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def gauss(x,mu,sigma,A):
    return A*np.exp(-(x-mu)**2/2/sigma**2)

def bimodal(x,mu1,sigma1,A1,mu2,sigma2,A2):
    return gauss(x,mu1,sigma1,A1)+gauss(x,mu2,sigma2,A2)

def rmse(p0):
    mu1,sigma1,A1,mu2,sigma2,A2 =p0
    y_sim = bimodal(x,mu1,sigma1,A1,mu2,sigma2,A2)
    rms = np.sqrt((y-y_sim)**2/len(y))

data = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
x, y = data.index, data['24hr'].values

expected=(400,720,500,700,774,150)

params,cov=curve_fit(bimodal,x,y,expected, maxfev=100000)
sigma=np.sqrt(np.diag(cov))
plt.plot(x,bimodal(x,*params),color='red',lw=3,label='model')
plt.plot(x,y,label='data')
plt.legend()
print(params,'\n',sigma)
```

Comment: Why are you using Gaussians?  The big peak is highly skewed, and looks almost triangular.

Comment: I used Gaussian because the data in later phases spreaded to loose bimodality and look like Gaussian distribution. I wanted to keep the fitting parameters uniform for inter data comparison in later phase.

Comment: I haven't tried to run your code, but from looking at the result, you might not be doing anything wrong.  Suppose one of the modes lined up nicely with the small peak on the right.  Then the other Gaussian mode has to somehow fit the big, skewed, non-Gaussian peak, which it can't do without a pretty high RMS error.  There is probably a much smaller overall error when the two modes are combined in a way that reduces the error required to match the big peak, despite not fitting the small peak very well.

Comment: Thanks for pointing in this direction. Then probably I need to change the type of distributions in the bimodal distribution function. I will look into it.

Comment: I have an example of using scipy's scipy.optimize.differential_evolution genetic algorithm to determine initial parameters for fitting a double Lorentzian peak equation to Raman spectroscopy data of carbon nanotubes here https://bitbucket.org/zunzuncode/RamanSpectroscopyFit - replace the equation and data with your own and you should be done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try a [skewed Gaussian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew_normal_distribution). With the parameter `alpha->0` this becomes a normal Gaussian, allowing somewhat for comparison:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.special import erf
from scipy.optimize import minimize,leastsq, curve_fit


def gauss(x):
    return np.exp( -0.5 * x**2 / np.sqrt( 2 * np.pi ) )


def Phi(x):
    return ( 0.5 * ( 1. + erf(x/np.sqrt(2) ) ) )


def skewed(x, x0, s, a):
    return 2./s * gauss( ( x - x0 ) / s ) * Phi( a * ( x - x0 ) / s)


def my_double_peak(x, A0, x0, s0, a, A1, x1, s1):
    return A0 * skewed( x, x0, s0, a ) + A1 / s1 * gauss( ( x - x1 ) / s1 )

data = np.loadtxt("data.csv", skiprows=1, delimiter=',')
xData = range(len(data))

fitResult, ier = curve_fit( my_double_peak, xData, data[:,1], p0=(45e3, 400., 60,4. ,15e3, 700., 30 )  ) 
print fitResult
bestFit = [my_double_peak(x, *fitResult ) for x in range(len(data)) ]


fig1=plt.figure(1)
ax= fig1.add_subplot( 1, 1, 1 )
ax.plot( data[:,1] )
ax.plot( bestFit )

plt.show()
```

Providing:

```
>>> [  6.77971459e+04   3.48661227e+02   8.60938473e+01   
       8.43422033e+00   3.86660495e+03   7.22528635e+02   
       2.49055201e+01]
```

[image: Fit with skewed gaussian]

Comment: What method did you use to determine values for the p0 initial parameters in your code?

Comment: @JamesPhillips At the moment I just used *educated guess*. For an automatized approach I'd need to know more about the data, e.g., can one assume that the not-skewed peak is always on the right, or has the skewness always the same sign, etc. It is not foolproof, but it is rather robust. E.g. `p0=(1700, 400., 1., 1. , 1700 / 3., 2 * 400., 1. )` works. Hence, you only  need to know the approx max value and assume that the second Gaussian is smaller and approx `2 * x0` on the right, setting the sigmas and the skewness `1`. Other simple assumptions might work for the real data.

Comment: Thank you - based on what I can see, your educated guesses work rather very well.