# How to fit a Gaussian best fit for the data

Tags: matplotlib, scipy, curve-fitting, gaussian

I have a data set for which I am plotting a graph of time vs intensity at a particular frequency.

On the x axis is the time data set which is in a numpy array and on the y axis is the intensity array.

```
time = [ 0.3  1.3  2.3  3.3  4.3  5.3  6.3  7.3  8.3  9.3 10.3 11.3 12.3 13.3
 14.3 15.3 16.3 17.3 18.3 19.3 20.3 21.3 22.3 23.3 24.3 25.3 26.3 27.3
 28.3 29.3 30.3 31.3 32.3 33.3 34.3 35.3 36.3 37.3 38.3 39.3 40.3 41.3
 42.3 43.3 44.3 45.3 46.3 47.3 48.3 49.3 50.3 51.3 52.3 53.3 54.3 55.3
 56.3 57.3 58.3 59.3] 

intensity = [1.03587, 1.03187, 1.03561, 1.02893, 1.04659, 1.03633, 1.0481 ,
       1.04156, 1.02164, 1.02741, 1.02675, 1.03651, 1.03713, 1.0252 ,
       1.02853, 1.0378 , 1.04374, 1.01427, 1.0387 , 1.03389, 1.03148,
       1.04334, 1.042  , 1.04154, 1.0161 , 1.0469 , 1.03152, 1.22406,
       5.4362 , 7.92132, 6.50259, 4.7227 , 3.32571, 2.46484, 1.74615,
       1.51446, 1.2711 , 1.15098, 1.09623, 1.0697 , 1.06085, 1.05837,
       1.04151, 1.0358 , 1.03574, 1.05095, 1.03382, 1.04629, 1.03636,
       1.03219, 1.03555, 1.02886, 1.04652, 1.02617, 1.04363, 1.03591,
       1.04199, 1.03726, 1.03246, 1.0408 ]
```

When I plot this using matplotlib, using;

```
plt.figure(figsize=(15,6))
plt.title('Single frequency graph at 636 kHz', fontsize=18)
plt.plot(time,intensity)
plt.xticks(time[::3], fontsize=12)
plt.yticks(fontsize=12)
plt.xlabel('Elapsed time (minutes:seconds)', fontsize=18)
plt.ylabel('Intensity at 1020 kHz', fontsize=18)
plt.savefig('WIND_Single_frequency_graph_1020_kHz')
plt.show()
```

The graph looks like -

[image]

I want to fit a gaussian curve for this data, and this is the code I used,

```
def Gauss(x, A, B):
    y = A*np.exp(-1*B*x**2)
    return y
parameters, covariance = curve_fit(Gauss, time, intensity_636)


fit_A = parameters[0]
fit_B = parameters[1]

fit_y = Gauss(time, fit_A, fit_B)

plt.figure(figsize=(15,6))
plt.plot(time, intensity, 'o', label = 'data')
plt.plot(time, fit_y, '-', label ='fit')
plt.legend()
```

And the best fit i obtain looks like this -

[image]

Where am I going wrong? How can I make the best fit curve fit the data better?

Comment: You trying to fit a guassian centered around zero, which looks quite flat in your x-range.  You'll probably want to introduce an extra parameter to shift the curve.  Maybe something like `A*np.exp(-B*(x-C)**2)`? Note that the more parameters you try to fit, the more problems with fitting accuracy and possibility to get stuck in a weird local minimum.

Comment: @JohanC Im not sure I understand what you mean.. could you explain a bit more?

Comment: Well, your gauss function only allows a peak at zero, while the peak of your data is clearly somewhere else.   Also note that the gauss function approaches y=zero when further away from the peak, while your data suggest y=1 away from the peak.

Comment: Looks quite skewed. Maybe you have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47133018/803359) as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define a more flexible model (more parameters) and to define reasonable initial values for them:

```py
def f(x, a, b, mu, sigma):
    return a + b * np.exp(-(x - mu) ** 2 / (2 * sigma ** 2))

popt, pcov = curve_fit(f, time, intensity, p0=[1, 1, 30.3, 2])

plt.plot(time, intensity)
plt.plot(time, f(time, *popt))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! @blunova if i could ask a question, how do you obtain this - p0=[1, 1, 30.3, 2] and what does it mean??

Comment: I've just assumed those values, there is no particular calculation behind them. For instance, the parameter `a` controls the vertical translation of the curve, so I set it to 1.0 (as you can clearly see from the graph), `mu` is approximately 30.0 by looking at the curve again, etc.

Answer (score 1):

By inspection one obweve that the curve isn't symmetrical. This is even more visible in logarithmic y-scale zoomed in the range close to the peak.

[image]

This draw to think that the Gaussian model (which is symetrical) cannot be fitted correctly.

Also one observe that the part of the curve around the peak isn't far from to be linear. Thus a better model might be made of the combination of two exponential functions, for example :

[image]

[image]

I suppose that you can code this function in your nonlinear regression sofware. The above rough values of the parameters can be used as starting values for the iterative calculus.